# Is there a divergent sequence such that for every n in N it is possible to find n consecutive twos somewhere in the sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Is there a divergent sequence such that for every n in N it is possible to find n consecutive twos somewhere in the sequence.

My thoughts are sequences as : { 1 , 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, ...}    or something like the whole |N and then we follow with inf. twos .

I dont know how to write this as a function/sequence form like   an = .... .

Help appreciated! :)

Comment: Start with the sequence of all $2$'s and replace every power of $2$ by a $1$.

Comment: You have "n consecutive twos" in the title and "n consecutive ones" in the question. Also, do you mean "at least n consecutive twos" or "exactly n consecutive twos"?

Comment: I was a bit confused by that discrepancy (the one TonyK points out), but it's trivial to convert a sequence for one meaning to a sequence for the other, so it doesn't matter much. Both are possible (and it's obvious that the second implies the first), but Ethan's construction only achieves the first.

Comment: Oh i am sorry just saw the comments. I mean only 2‘s i wanted to write ‚two‘ instead of ‚one‘

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an infinite sequence of $2$'s and intersperse it with the terms of some divergent sequence, each time increasing the distance.

Like

$$\begin{cases}T_{n(n+1)/2}&=S_n,\\T_{k,k\ne n(n+1)/2}&=2.\end{cases}$$